# Access to configuration option in Xcode

Tags: xcode

ALL,

In *nix, the usual way of building the software is to do:

```
../configure && make && make install
```

However sometimes you need to pass some options to configure. As an example you can say "../configure --prefix=".

Now sometimes configure has a lot of programmer defined options. As an example if I want to build a freeTDS software (driver to access MS SQL Server/Sybase Server) I can choose which DBMS I want to build against thru "--enable-mssql/--enable-Sybase".

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Xcode, however I do know that OSX is a type of *nix environment.

So my question is: do I have access to such configure options inside Xcode? Let's say I am building a software that uses ODBC. So I can use either unixODBC DM or iODBC DM. And so my thought is that I can use "--with-unixodbc/--with-iodbc" mutually exclusive configure options. But inside Xcode I have no idea where/how to define those.

Could someone please shed some light, please?

I have OSX 10.8 with the latest Xcode for that version, if it matters.

[EDIT]

On Linux when building pgodbc, I can use:

```
../configure --with-unixodbc=<some_dir>
```

or

```
../configure --with-iodbc=<some_dir>
```

Is there a way to tell Xcode I want to build with one OR another? Or you just build as many binaries as you wish?

Becase iODBC manager installs its files as a framework and unixODBC build from source installs as usual *nix file. So, when I build I want to know what I am testing against and what the user machine will have...

[/EDIT]

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @retainCount, just tried to clarify that. Can you take a look?

Comment: Are you generating an xcodeproj for iODBC? Customizing the calls to configure will be specific to how the xcodeproj is set up as Xcode doesn't use configure/make. Some projects might be configured to shell out to those tools directly, which is what I imagine you're seeing.

Comment: @retainCount, right now it is set up to compile against iODBC. But if the user does not have this DM and have unixODBC instead. I'm not sure what will happen. Also, I'm not seeing anything - I'm trying to compare Linux with OSX build systems, since both are *nix'es.